# Form-Fielding Japanese with PDFtk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdftk

Good day everyone,

I have an already existing application that form fields PDFs based on user input. It uses PDFtk and works great for English text, however we are now trying to make it work for Japanese text and I am having an issue where text does not display unless you click inside of a field. It appears to be displaying in a different font that the English text, but I don't know if that is the reason it isn't working.

Does anyone know how to make the PDF recognize the characters that are present in the field and display them using PDFtk?

If anyone needs more specifics or clarification I would be happy to provide more context.

Best,